# ViewController file not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am new to iOS and I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong.

So in my main.storyboard file, I added a tab view (also checked is initial view controller)

When I added a tab view, Xcode created a two view controller(?) and tabs for me.

In one of those I added a class `CreateMeetingViewController` and then created a swift file for the same

In the swift file, I put a debugger in `super.viewDidLoad()` to see if this file is being called but the debugger never reaches there and I am still able to see the desired screen

**Question:** Can someone please help me in understanding how I can connect viewController with swift file?

```
class CreateMeetingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Watch the console. Do you not see a warning message about CreateMeetingViewController?

Comment: Your storyboard class has no module selected. Select Class from the drop-down.